# CSS hover menu not showing with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time getting a menu to show up beside a list of items when a user hovers over the item.  The list of items is within a div that has overflow-y: auto which seems to be cutting off the popup.

The idea of this is that the user will be able to scroll down the list and hover over a list item to view more details.  The top positions of the popup should match the top position of the list item.  Also, when the user hovers over into the popup, the popup should stay open as well.

I have created a fiddle to describe the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/k4n10t1s/8/

HTML:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
.item {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
}
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
}
.item:hover > .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
      Hover Here - Half the gray box is missing
      <div class="popup">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Hover Here - Half the gray box is missing
      <div class="popup">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Hover Here - Half the gray box is missing
      <div class="popup">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Hover Here - Half the gray box is missing
      <div class="popup">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Hover Here - Half the gray box is missing
      <div class="popup">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this what you're after https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/k4n10t1s/9/ ?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity the idea is right but I would like div with the class 'inner' to be scroll-able (contained by the outer container).

Comment: changing your .popup left: -100px to 0px fixed your problem?

Comment: @Syahrul I would like the popup to be outside of the item container.  If i change left to 0.  The popup will be within the item container.